# Highcharts / jQuery - destroy and rebuild chart with original options

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Based on info in this thread: [Implement own state - INACTIVE_STATE?](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10262)

I have built a chart that fits my needs - [jsfiddle](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10262)

I added some custom controls to allow the user to show/hide all series and to check/uncheck all series.

These all work fine.

The last part that I want to do is allow the user to reset the chart with the original options.

This part I also got working, but there is a problem: once the chart is rebuilt, the functions that allow the user to show/hide/check/uncheck no longer work because I have destroyed and re-specified the variable that they run off of.

So my question(s) -

1. is this the right way to destroy and rebuild the chart, or is there a better method?
2. if this is the way to do it, then how do I get my show/hide/check/uncheck functions to continue to work afterward?

The code to reset the chart is here:

```
//reset the chart to original specs
$('#resetChart').click(function(){
    chart1.destroy();
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsChart1,highlightSer);
});
```

`highlightSer` is a call back function to highlight certain series.

an example of the code which no longer works afterward:

```
var chart = chart1;
$('#showAll').click(function(){
        for(i=0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        chart.series[i].show();
    }
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> 1) is this the right way to destroy and rebuild the chart, or is there a better method?

That's the only way and Highcharts is smart enough so that you don't have to worry about any memory leaks.

> 2) if this is the way to do it, then how do I get my show/hide/check/uncheck functions to continue to work afterward?

You are recreating the chart but not assigning it to the variable `chart` again.

```
$('#resetChart').click(function(){
    chart1.destroy();
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsChart1,highlightSer);
    chart = chart1; // <-------- Add this line here.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason for assigning the chart to a new variable here?

```
var chart = chart1;
```

`chart` will not point to a graph anymore after you have destroyed it. If you just use `chart1`, which you re–assign, everything [**seems to work just fine**](http://jsfiddle.net/57SR9/14/). Or am I missing something?