# how to destroy highcharts object

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

when i open a page with highcharts more than twice.i got an error like this:

```
    Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
```

and detail is:

```
    Highcharts Error #16

    Highcharts already defined in the page

    This error happens the second time Highcharts or Highstock is loaded in 
    the same page, so the Highcharts namespace is already defined. Keep in 
    mind that the Highcharts.Chart constructor and all features of Highcharts
     are included in Highstock, so if you are running Chart and StockChart 
    in combination, you only need to load the highstock.js file.
```

it is telling me highcharts object is already exist.so, how can i destroy object when i reopen a page with highcharts.
here is my code:

```
    $(function(){
      chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
              renderTo: 'container1',
              type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'count'
            },
            credits: {
              enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [  ],
                crosshair: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: '商家个数'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '{point.key}',
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: ' +
                    '{point.y} 个',
                footerFormat: '',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [
              {
                name: 'count',
                data: 
              }
            ]
        });
    });
```

any help will be appreciate.....

Comment: Check this link might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364172/highcharts-error-16-charts-not-showing-on-the-same-page

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work.....

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the error. That error means you loaded twice `highcharts.js` file. It's not about creating chart..

Comment: this may help you destroy highchart object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880978/highcharts-jquery-destroy-and-rebuild-chart-with-original-options