# Highcharts : using same div to load a chart multiple times with different series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts, appcelerator-titanium

I have written a function that creates a chart based on some graphdata as parameter and renders it to a div . Now I am reusing this function to generate same type of chart on same div to load different series data . The problem is I can see the graph rendering shows previous charts labels for a second and then the new graph gets loaded with new labels . I dont want to see the old graph when my new graph gets loaded . Please help .

My chart function :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./jquery.min.jsl"></script>
    <script src="./highcharts.jsl"></script>
    <script src="./exporting.jsl"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
    <script>

        function renderGraph(graphdata) {
            var graphObj = JSON.parse(graphdata);
            var chart = null; 
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                lang : {
                    numericSymbols : ["K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"]
                }
            });
            var change = {
                0 : '$0K',
                2 : '$2K',
                4 : '$4K',
                6 : '$6K',
                8 : '$8K'
            };
            var xAxisLegends = graphObj.bottomLegends;
            var seriesData = graphObj.seriesData;
            var xAxisLegends = graphObj.bottomLegends;
            //['Q2, 16', 'Q3, 16', 'Q4, 16', 'Q1, 17'];
            var columnColors = ["#69C3DB", "#3a8a9f"];

            var seriesData = graphObj.seriesData;
            /*[{
            name : 'Budget',
            showInLegend : false,
            data : [2, 4, 6, 8]
            }, {
            name : 'Utilisation',
            showInLegend : false,
            data : [1, 2, 3, 4]
            }];*/

            // variables which have diff values according to OS
            var chartProperties = {};
            // properties to assign to Charts's object
            var graphHeight = 0;
            // height of chart
            var graphWidth = 0;
            //Width of the column
            var pointWidth;

            // Separating the graph dimensions & styling properties as per OS name & version
            if (graphObj.osname == "iphone") {
                chartProperties = {
                    type : 'column',
                    renderTo : 'container'
                };
                xAxisProp = {
                    gridLineWidth : 0,
                    categories : xAxisLegends,
                    crosshair : true
                };
                yAxisProp = {
                    min : 0,
                    gridLineWidth : 0,
                    tickAmount : 5,
                    title : {
                        text : ' '
                    },
                    labels : {
                        formatter : function() {
                            var value = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                            return '$' + value;
                        }
                    }
                };
                pointWidth = 5;
            } else if (graphObj.osname == "android") {
                chartProperties = {
                    type : 'column',
                    plotBackgroundColor : null,
                    plotBackgroundImage : null,
                    plotBorderWidth : 0,
                    plotShadow : false,
                    height : 450,
                    marginTop : 100,
                    marginLeft : 120

                },
                xAxisProp = {
                    categories : xAxisLegends,
                    width : 800,
                    tickmarkPlacement : 'on',
                    labels : {
                        y : 40,
                        style : {
                            color : '#333333',
                            fontSize : '25',
                            fontFamily : 'Metropolis-Light',
                            opacity : '.6'
                        },

                    }
                };
                yAxisProp = {
                    gridLineWidth : 0,
                    min : 0,
                    tickAmount : 5,
                    offset : 60,
                    title : {
                        text : ''
                    },
                    labels : {
                        align : 'left',
                        style : {
                            color : '#333333',
                            fontSize : '28',
                            fontFamily : 'Metropolis-Light',
                            opacity : '.5'
                        },
                        formatter : function() {
                            var value = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                            return '$' + value;
                        }
                    },

                };
                pointWidth = 10;
                if (parseInt(graphObj.osversion) >= 500 && parseInt(graphObj.osversion) <= 600) {
                    graphHeight = 600;
                } else {
                    graphHeight = 630;
                }
            }
            chart = 
                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart : chartProperties,
                    credits : {
                        enabled : false
                    },
                    tooltip : {
                        enabled : false
                    },
                    exporting : {
                        enabled : false
                    },
                    title : {
                        text : ''
                    },
                    xAxis : xAxisProp,
                    yAxis : yAxisProp,
                    plotOptions : {
                        column : {
                            pointPadding : 0.2,
                            borderWidth : 0,
                            groupPadding : 0.38,
                            pointWidth : pointWidth
                        }
                    },
                    colors : columnColors,
                    series : seriesData
                });


        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position : center;"></div>
</body>
```

The function that calls this chart :

```
 $.webViewPerformanceGraph.url = "/html/Performance.html";

            $.webViewPerformanceGraph.addEventListener('load', function() {
                $.webViewPerformanceGraph.evalJS("renderGraph('" + JSON.stringify(params) + "');");
```

Comment: You should probably `destroy()` the chart before loading up the new one. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880978/highcharts-jquery-destroy-and-rebuild-chart-with-original-options as well as this documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#destroy.

Comment: I tried the destroy() in beginning of renderGraph() but of no avail . Can you point some insights onto where to call the destroy() .in my custom function() @wergeld

Comment: As given in API sample above in comments. There is variable `var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {...})`  where you used in renderGraph() function

Comment: @Deep3015 I have added var chart in my code . Please tell me where to put destroy(). Plz note there wont be any button to destroy the graph in the code .

Comment: @AbhishekAnand check this http://jsfiddle.net/g6n0ep44/

Comment: @Deep3015 I implemented the destroy(). It didnt work out . When this function renderGraph gets called , I can still see the y axis labels changing according to the data . And all the old labels get seen , means if I have called the function 9 times , it will show all the previous y axis labels of the 9 previous calls , then the new labels come.

Comment: I prepared a minimal demo based on your code and comments: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/begqpt43/ Everything seems to look good in it. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using jQuery, have you tried simply emptying the container div as follows before redrawing the chart?

```
$('#container').html();
```

Perhaps this would be more beneficial since `chart.destroy()` doesn't seem to be working in your case.

From http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2:

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.