# appcelerator : webview to show graph using HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, titanium, eval, appcelerator-titanium

I am developing an application which sends data to a webview and it uses highcharts to draw graph . The problem I am facing is I am using same graph to display different data series , so when I am calling the graph for 10th time , it firsts shows the y axis labels of all the previous 9 graphs , then the graph is loaded with labels of 10th graph . Any help .

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./jquery.min.jsl"></script>
    <script src="./highcharts.jsl"></script>
    <script src="./exporting.jsl"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
    <script>

        function renderGraph(graphdata) {
            var graphObj = JSON.parse(graphdata);
            var chart = null; 
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                lang : {
                    numericSymbols : ["K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"]
                }
            });
            var change = {
                0 : '$0K',
                2 : '$2K',
                4 : '$4K',
                6 : '$6K',
                8 : '$8K'
            };
            var xAxisLegends = graphObj.bottomLegends;
            var seriesData = graphObj.seriesData;
            var xAxisLegends = graphObj.bottomLegends;
            //['Q2, 16', 'Q3, 16', 'Q4, 16', 'Q1, 17'];
            var columnColors = ["#69C3DB", "#3a8a9f"];

            var seriesData = graphObj.seriesData;
            /*[{
            name : 'Budget',
            showInLegend : false,
            data : [2, 4, 6, 8]
            }, {
            name : 'Utilisation',
            showInLegend : false,
            data : [1, 2, 3, 4]
            }];*/

            // variables which have diff values according to OS
            var chartProperties = {};
            // properties to assign to Charts's object
            var graphHeight = 0;
            // height of chart
            var graphWidth = 0;
            //Width of the column
            var pointWidth;

            // Separating the graph dimensions & styling properties as per OS name & version
            if (graphObj.osname == "iphone") {
                chartProperties = {
                    type : 'column',
                    renderTo : 'container'
                };
                xAxisProp = {
                    gridLineWidth : 0,
                    categories : xAxisLegends,
                    crosshair : true
                };
                yAxisProp = {
                    min : 0,
                    gridLineWidth : 0,
                    tickAmount : 5,
                    title : {
                        text : ' '
                    },
                    labels : {
                        formatter : function() {
                            var value = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                            return '$' + value;
                        }
                    }
                };
                pointWidth = 5;
            } else if (graphObj.osname == "android") {
                chartProperties = {
                    type : 'column',
                    plotBackgroundColor : null,
                    plotBackgroundImage : null,
                    plotBorderWidth : 0,
                    plotShadow : false,
                    height : 450,
                    marginTop : 100,
                    marginLeft : 120

                },
                xAxisProp = {
                    categories : xAxisLegends,
                    width : 800,
                    tickmarkPlacement : 'on',
                    labels : {
                        y : 40,
                        style : {
                            color : '#333333',
                            fontSize : '25',
                            fontFamily : 'Metropolis-Light',
                            opacity : '.6'
                        },

                    }
                };
                yAxisProp = {
                    gridLineWidth : 0,
                    min : 0,
                    tickAmount : 5,
                    offset : 60,
                    title : {
                        text : ''
                    },
                    labels : {
                        align : 'left',
                        style : {
                            color : '#333333',
                            fontSize : '28',
                            fontFamily : 'Metropolis-Light',
                            opacity : '.5'
                        },
                        formatter : function() {
                            var value = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                            return '$' + value;
                        }
                    },

                };
                pointWidth = 10;
                if (parseInt(graphObj.osversion) >= 500 && parseInt(graphObj.osversion) <= 600) {
                    graphHeight = 600;
                } else {
                    graphHeight = 630;
                }
            }
            chart = 
                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart : chartProperties,
                    credits : {
                        enabled : false
                    },
                    tooltip : {
                        enabled : false
                    },
                    exporting : {
                        enabled : false
                    },
                    title : {
                        text : ''
                    },
                    xAxis : xAxisProp,
                    yAxis : yAxisProp,
                    plotOptions : {
                        column : {
                            pointPadding : 0.2,
                            borderWidth : 0,
                            groupPadding : 0.38,
                            pointWidth : pointWidth
                        }
                    },
                    colors : columnColors,
                    series : seriesData
                });


        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position : center;"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the function inside the controller which calls the graph using evalJS.

```
 $.webViewPerformanceGraph.url = "/html/Performance.html";

            $.webViewPerformanceGraph.addEventListener('load', function() {
                $.webViewPerformanceGraph.evalJS("renderGraph('" + JSON.stringify(params) + "');");
```

Comment: Is this the same question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811451/highcharts-using-same-div-to-load-a-chart-multiple-times-with-different-series#comment84693113_48811451

Comment: Nope @KamilKulig

Comment: Could you provide a minimal **live** demo (jsfiddle ideally) and describe steps to reproduce this issue?